Token from .env is undefined when fetching data NUXT 3
I'm trying to fetch data from api, as always i need to secure my token that backend given. Using useRuntimeConfig that documentation of Nuxt given. But This always getting undefined value of token.
<script setup lang="ts">
  interface User {
    nama: string;
  }

  const pending = ref(true)
  const data = ref < User > ()

  onMounted(async() => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/users', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Basic ${useRuntimeConfig().TOKEN}`,
      },
    })
    const users = await response.json()
    data.value = users
    pending.value = false
  })
</script>

Get solution that can store data from .env

What if you call and store useRuntimeConfig in a variable first?

@kissu It produces undefined. Also when console log that produce undefined at first render, and get the token when running ssr

Where are you checking? Browser console or terminal console? Both are different environments.

@kissu Both of them. Undefined in the browser and getting the value in the terminal console

There is no mounted lifecycle on the server. It's only client side.

Do you still have the error with this taken into account? :)

@kissu enough sir. maybe need to delete this question too? because that not clear question. Thankyou for helping me

Hm, no need to delete anything it's okay. Keep it like that for future reference. Not a big deal if it's stays here. You're welcome!
